# How insert multiple arrays in a single query using php and sql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm trying to insert multiple arrays coming from $_POST form, but even trying some methods like "while()" and"foreach()" i didn't got success. Is the first time i'm doing this using arrays, so i'm very lost.

My code is:

```
<input type='text' id="productName[]" name="productName[]">

<input type='text' id="quantity[]" name="quantity[]">

include_once("connection.php");

 $name = $_POST['productName'];
 $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];

$name = '"' . implode('","', $name) . '"';
$quantity = '"' . implode('","', $quantity) . '"';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE name IN ($name)";
$result = mysqli_query($conn_app, $sql);
if (mysqli_affected_rows($conn_app) > 0){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $itemId = $row['product_id'];
    };

$insert = "INSERT INTO item_box (quantity,product_id) VALUES ('$quantity','$itemId')";
$result = mysqli_query($conn_app, $insert);
```

I expect the result to insert rows for each array that exist.
like:

```
"INSERT INTO item_box (quantity,product_id) VALUES ("20","3")";
"INSERT INTO item_box (quantity,product_id) VALUES ("50","5")";...
```

but i'm getting a error result (many quantity values and a single product_id) like:

```
"INSERT INTO item_box (quantity,product_id) VALUES ("20","30","40","50","2")"
```

Comment: And if you want to insert multiple rows, then put the insert instructions INSIDE the while loop

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Comment: @RiggsFolly if i've tried put inside the while loop, but the "quantity" keeps giving many values at the same time into the query.

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple arrays in a single query using

```
INSERT INTO a VALUES (1,23),(2,34),(4,33);


INSERT INTO a VALUES (8,26),(6,29);
```

Comment: thanks for answer, but is not clear for me how to do it

Comment: you can use like that INSERT INTO item_box (quantity,product_id) VALUES (1,23),(2,34),(4,33);

Comment: okay, but how to pass the array to be like you're showing? because is the quantity array is coming with (20,30,40) i need insert each product_id and respective quantity.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `implode` function to convert all the `array` element to `string` and using the same to insert

```
$quantity = '"' . implode('","', $quantity) . '"';
```

So this will convert each array element to like `one, two, three`.

The variable `quantity` should have a single digit value.

For example:-

```
$quantity = array(20);
```

You code

```
$quantity = '"' . implode('","', $quantity) . '"';
```

It will treat it as `"20"`

Now let's say if there are more values in the same array

```
$quantity = array(20,30,40);
```

You code

```
$quantity = '"' . implode('","', $quantity) . '"';
```

then it will be `"20","30","40"`

But you are updating 2 columns and this makes the query like `values("1","20","30","40")`, you will get an error because of this.

You need to find which array element value you need to use for `quantity`

OR

I am not sure but maybe you are looking for `array_sum`, so when

```
$quantity = array(20,30,40);

$quantity = '"' .array_sum($quantity). '"';
```

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Comment: this is wrong. every iteration you send mysql query

Comment: @RiggsFolly he is not asking for the SQL injection, he is asking why its not inserting for each iteration.

Comment: @RakeshJakhar how can i make it a single digit value and insert for each row? when i insert a single array value is fine, but when is multiple values don't work.

Comment: sorry if i miss something. i understand what you've said and is true. but i don't know how to separate it and insert each quantity on each product_id.
like
(product_id, quantity)VALUES (1,23),(2,34),(4,33);

Answer (score 0):

this code is working, but is inserting the same data as many arrays exist. I don't know how to fix.

```
foreach($_POST["productName"] as $produto){
foreach($_POST["quantity"] as $quantidade){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE name = '$produto'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn_app, $sql);
if (mysqli_affected_rows($conn_app) > 0){
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
$itemId = $row['product_id'];
$insert = "INSERT INTO item_box (quantity,product_id) VALUES ('$quantidade','$itemId')";
$result = mysqli_query($conn_app, $insert);
};
}
}
}
```